# Tengo mi función asíncrona, pero no me la quiere recorrer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, moongose

lo que pasa es que quiero traer todo la información que esta en mi base de datos en mongodb que lo estoy utilizando con mongoose y lo quiero recorrer pero me dice que el foreach esta indifinido y no se que pueda ser .

me pueden ayudar, Gracias.

```
async function followUSerIds(user_id) {
  var following = await Follow.find({ user: user_id })
    .select({ _id: 0, __v: 0, user: 0 })
    .then((err, follows) => {
      return follows;
    });
    console.log(following);

  var followed = await Follow.find({ followed: user_id })
    .select({ _id: 0, __v: 0, followed: 0 })
    .then((err, follows) => {
        return follows;
    });

  //procesar following ids
  const following_clean = [];
  following.forEach((follow) => {
    following_clean.push(follow.followed);
  });

  //procesar followed ids
  const followed_clean = [];
  followed.forEach((follow) => {
    followed_clean.push(follow.user);
  });

  return {
    following: following_clean,
    followed: followed_clean,
  };
}
```

este es el error que me sale al momento de ejecutarlo "(node:33624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la salida del `console.log`? ¿Que se está guardando en las variables `following` y `followed`?. Lo más probable es que no sea un array y por eso de el error de que no existe el `forEach`. Comenta todos los `forEach` y revisa que hay en las variables followed y following. Verifica que sea un array.

Comment: acabó de hacer la prueba y me arroja un undefined afuera de la variables, pero si lo hago a dentro de cada variable si me manda la información

Comment: Si ya hiciste una pregunta por favor no la dupliques, repetir la pregunta no hará que te ayuden más rápido. Edita esta pregunta para agregar más detalles y elimina la otra ó elimina esta y continua con la [original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490358/porque-mi-funci%c3%b3n-as%c3%adncrona-en-nodejs-me-esta-retornando-undefiend).

Comment: Estás mezclando Promesas con callbacks, ese es un error.

Comment: me podrías decir cual seria la mejor opción